# We run several offers during festive seasons. Is there a way to create interactive labels for products to advertise our marketing campaigns?

Tags: magento2, product, labels, product-lables

So right now I am using the magento2 platform and I want my site to look more presentable to the customer after my research I am inclined to move towards creating labels for products. However, I am not well versed in Magento code so not sure how to achieve this. If someone can help me with the code or suggest a module to achieve this then it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below extension,

1. https://marketplace.magento.com/sparsh-magento-2-product-label-extension.html
2. https://amasty.com/product-labels-for-magento-2.html ( **Paid** )
3. https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-configure-create-product-labels-in-magento-2-store/